# Can I do a fast enumeration directly via a property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, for-loop, enumeration

if I have a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* myArray;
```

Can I do ? And if yes why does this work ?

```
for (id object in self.myArray)
    ;
```

Or do I need to do ?

```
NSArray* r = self.myArray;
for (id object in r)
    ;
```

Comment: Did you try it? You could've found the answer in about 20 seconds.

Comment: Actually I'm more in interested in why it works. Is it a compiler optimization ? How can the loop now that the self.myArray is always the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because self.myArray is syntactical sugar for [self myArray], which is generated by the @synthesize keyword.  So really you're doing:

```
for (id object in [self myArray])
```

And the return value of [self myArray] implements the fast enumeration protocol so the for..in syntax can work on it.

Does that make things clearer?

Comment: I would also add that a standard read/writeable property has two functions generated by the @synthesize: myArray and setMyArray.  Also this information can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use fast enumeration like that. To answer the question from your comments, I believe that the fast enumeration protocol will throw an exception if you modify your array property during enumeration.

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely go for `for(id object in self.array)`